# How do I set a variable in separate widget class from custom button widget class in ue4 blueprint

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

attached are my current blueprints. i have a widget that is the level select screen, which will contain instances of a level select button. depending on which button is clicked, i want it to update a variable in the level select widget which stores the level from that particular button. I'm trying to do this so that i can add or remove levels from the selector in a modular way, as well as because there will be an option to select multiple levels played one after the other.

https://i.gyazo.com/71731a6682b186b0e1b874a80144677c.png is the button code, when clicked it will take the editor value as an int, and (when working properly) send that to the level select code which is pictured here https://i.gyazo.com/277e54770aa1a70bdab083f8b98aa714.png, selecting the proper level based on the value of variable 'selected level' when the 'proceed' button is clicked.

Comment: Where does the level select code live? Also, what does the error say?

Comment: Are the proceed button and the level select buttons contained in the same widget?

Comment: It might be best to set the selected level sequence in something like a Game Instance (`UGameInstance`) because it is meant to persist between levels.

Comment: Level select code lives in a widget blueprint named 'level select' which then displays the widgets such as the proceed button and the level select button. The error is https://i.gyazo.com/1f98a4b62bb59bf8af661095c1308580.png, which i believe means i need to cast in some way but ive had no luck with that.

Comment: Game instance appears to be exactly the type of thing im looking for, thank you very much!